# sed can't edit ssl.conf "Permission denied"

Tags: php, sed, centos, permission-denied

I'm trying to edit /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf with bash file I called from PHP `exec`:

```
 #comment those lines in ssl.conf
    sed -i 's/^SSLCertificateFile/#SSLCertificateFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
    sed -i 's/^SSLCertificateKeyFile/#SSLCertificateKeyFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

 #uncomment those lines in ssl.conf
     sed -i 's/^#SSLCertificateFile/SSLCertificateFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
     sed -i 's/^#SSLCertificateKeyFile/SSLCertificateKeyFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

but I'm getting this error :

```
   sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/httpd/conf.d/sed3nRibG: Permission denied
   sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/httpd/conf.d/sed2ASgeG: Permission denied
```

I changed the owner to `apache` and permission to `a+xw` of the `ssl.conf` file but it didn't help . 
any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put hosts in a separate and change owner the whole folder :

```
chown apache:apache /etc/https/conf.d
chown apache:apache /etc/https/conf.d/*
```

and those the lines in bash :

```
  #comment those lines in vhosts.conf
    sed -i 's/^SSLCertificateFile/#SSLCertificateFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf
    sed -i 's/^SSLCertificateKeyFile/#SSLCertificateKeyFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf

  #uncomment those lines in vhosts.conf
    sed -i 's/^#SSLCertificateFile/SSLCertificateFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf
    sed -i 's/^#SSLCertificateKeyFile/SSLCertificateKeyFile/g' /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

sed tries to create a temp file... see the errors... and has no permission to write to the directory ( **/etc/httpd/conf.d** )

see [sed command creates randomly named files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733922/sed-command-creates-random-named-files) for possible other solutions