# Easily parse file permissions in msysgit on windows

Tags: windows, bash, msysgit

If I was using linux or cygwin I could use `stat --format=%a` as [described here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/82327-what-command-get-file-permission.html).

But instead I want to use only the tools available in msysgit by default. My main options seems to be parsing the output of ls, but that is not very palatable:

```
drwxr-xr-x    0 jaxelson Administ        0 Jul 13  2009 PrintHood/
dr-xr-xr-x    0 jaxelson Administ     8192 Jan  3 09:22 Recent/
```

Are there any easier ways?

Back History:
I need to do this because of a bug in `sed` where it doesn't preserve permissions correctly. For more info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823591/sed-creates-un-deleteable-files-in-windows).

Also the script that is running `sed` is running as a `git-hook`.

Comment: Hold on, how is this git-related at all?

Comment: @fge I guess it's not directly related. But it is running in the msysgit (git bash) environment as a git hook. I've clarified the answer a little bit and removed the git tag.

Comment: It might help to explain what tools you have available. Is there no stat command at all, or does it not support --format?

Comment: @jordanm there's no stat command at all. The main tools available are awk, sed and bash. Basically whatever is provided in the default Git Bash environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
perl -e'printf "%o\n",(stat shift)[2] & 07777' <filename>
```