# Why does sed leave many files around?

Tags: linux, sed

I noticed many files in my directory, called "sedAbCdEf" or such.

- Why does it create these files?
- Do these have any value after a script has run?
- Can I send these files to another location , e.g. `/tmp/`?

Update:

I checked the scripts until I found one which makes the files. Here is some sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
b=`wc -l < ./file1.txt`
while [ $a -le $b ]; do
    for i in `sed -n "$a"p ./file1.txt`; do
        for j in `sed -n "$a"p ./file2.txt`; do
            sed -i "s/$i/\nZZ$jZZ\n/g" ./file3.txt
            c=`grep -c $j file3.txt`
            if [ "$c" -ge 1 ]
            then
                echo $j >> file4.txt
                echo "Replaced "$i" with "$j" "$c" times ("$a"/"$b")."
            fi
                echo $i" not found ("$a"/"$b")."
            a=`expr $a + 1`
        done
    done
done
```

Comment: why do you think it is related to sed? except for the filename of course,

Comment: I suppose it could be made by something else, however, I find them after running BASH scripts and the BASH scripts contain `sed`. All of the filenames begin with "sed", followed by some random letters.

Comment: can you post the bash script? I am looking for a part that says `blabla > sedAbCdEf`?

Comment: @NiklasB.: `sed -i` creates files, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834294/4279)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Why does it create these files?

`sed -i "s/$i/\nZZ$jZZ\n/g" ./file3.txt`

the `-i` option makes `sed` stores the stdout output into a temporary file.
After `sed` is done, it will rename this temp file to replace your original `file3.txt`.
If something is wrong when `sed` is running, these `sedAbCdE` temp files will be left there.

- Do these have any value after a script has run?

Your old file is untouched. Usually no.

- Can I send these files to another location , e.g. /tmp/?

Yes you can, see above.

Edit: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823591/sed-creates-un-deleteable-files-in-windows) for further reading.

Comment: [The source code for GNU sed-4.2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834294/4279) as I understand it says that it is impossible to send these files to another location

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I think Village meant after all the script has stopped running, can confirm OP?

Answer (score 5):

If you use `-i` option (it means make changes inplace) `sed` writes to a temporary file and then renames it to your file. Thus if operation is aborted your file is left unchanged.

You can see which files are opened, renamed with `strace`:

```
$ strace -e open,rename sed -i 's/a/b/g' somefile
```

Note: `somefile` is opened as readonly.

It seems there is no way to override the backup directory. GNU sed always writes in the file's directory (±symlinks). From [sed/execute.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/tree/sed/execute.c?id=8b65e07904384b529a464c89f3739d2e7e4d5135#n574):

```
if (follow_symlinks)
  input->in_file_name = follow_symlink (name);
else
  input->in_file_name = name;

/* get the base name */
tmpdir = ck_strdup(input->in_file_name);
if ((p = strrchr(tmpdir, '/')))
  *(p + 1) = 0;
else
  strcpy(tmpdir, ".");
```

Prefix `sed` is hardcoded:

```
output_file.fp = ck_mkstemp (&input->out_file_name, tmpdir, "sed");
```

Comment: The temporary file has to be created in the same directory as the file it'll eventually be renamed over, otherwise you can't be sure the rename will work.  `sed` ought to be deleting its temporary files if it doesn't use them to replace the old files, though.

Answer (score 2):

This may be that, since you have used too much sed  actions, and in a looped pattern, sed may be making tmp files which are not removed properly.

[Sed creates un-deleteable files in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823591/sed-creates-un-deleteable-files-in-windows)

Take a look at this post, sed have such an issue to be reported before. The better way is to make a script that removes the files, or create a function that remove all files that deletes all files with name starting with sed, (^sed* )like thing.